# Regex to split a string but keep delimiters, but not as separate elements

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split the following string

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

into the following tokens:

1. the
2. quick brown fox jumps over the
3. lazy dog

So to explain, I want to split on `the` but include the `the` delimiter in the preceding array element (not as its own, separate element).

Can anyone shed any light on this or perhaps give me the correct regex?

I am using C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use look-behind (`?<=`). The name says it all, look at the previous characters to see if they match some given pattern.

This should work:

```
"(?<=\\bthe) "
```

So, at any space, check if the previous characters were `"the"`, if so, it matches.

Note - We also need to include the word boundary `\\b` (escaped `\b`) other-wise something like `"bathe"` will also match.

Without the look-behind, we'll check all the spaces:

```
   v     v     v   v     v    v   v    v
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

With the look-behind, we'll only match those the have `"the"` before it: (ignoring the `\\b` for now)

`"the "` - just found a space, and last characters are `"the"`, so match.
`"quick "` - just found another space, but last characters are `"...k"`, so no match.
etc.

[Test](http://ideone.com/Eur4Of).

Comment: That works great. Can you help me understand by giving the regex to split on "the" or "brown fox" for instance?

Comment: Think i got it. (?<=the|brown fox)

Comment: @Dukeling: Add `\b` before the `the` (not replacing space with `\b`). Otherwise, you will get weird result for `breathe`.